# CheckStyle change 2-space to 4-space indentation

Tags: java, yaml, checkstyle

I use a YAML file to generate the GitHub workflows that check Java code style. I use the google_checks.xml that uses 2-space indentation. How can I change it to a 4-space indentation?

This is the error I have:
`'member def modifier' has incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2.`

YAML file:

```
name: CheckStyle

on: [push]

jobs:
  analysis:
    name: CheckStyle
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8        
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: dbelyaev/action-checkstyle@v0.1.1
        with:
          checkstyle_config: google_checks.xml
          github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
          reporter: github-check
          level: warning
```

This is the GitHub repository that I am working on: https://github.com/annguyen23/Test3

Comment: Please, reformat your code in `src/main/java/IntStack.java`.

Comment: the java files are just for testing. My project is about using GitHub Action with checkstyle.

Answer (score 0):

Within the google_checks.xml there is a section as per the below example where the indent depth can be changed. The file google_checks.xml can be found in the checkstyle jar file.

```
<module name="Indentation">
  <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
  <property name="braceAdjustment" value="2"/>
  <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
  <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
  <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
  <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="2"/>
</module>
```